# I think it sounds dumb. Did special relativity already possess quantum field theory?

Tags: quantum-field-theory, special-relativity

Because when we look at the way Dirac got his equation he factored out the energy momentum relation in special relativity effectively and at a certain point he noted that there was that the factoring can only be done if the coefficients he introduced were anticommutator. And he finally noted the similarities with Pauli matrices with two additional components. Finally introducing the operators for energy and momentum he finally had his equation. But to me apparently it all seems like quantum mechanics just came out of special relativity.

Comment: Please try to choose proper titles for your question. "I think it sounds dumb" is entirely unnecessary here. Additionally, your title talks about quantum field theory and the end of your post about quantum mechanics - which one do you mean? Where exactly do you think either of them "came out of special relativity" here? The Dirac equation alone does not consititute "quantum theory".

Answer (score 1):

No they are seperate theories. Dirac just created relativistic quantum mechanics.

Relativity is a classical theory which treats objects without having any wavefunction.

Quantum mechanics is a quantum theory. For quantum objects with a big probability of travelling close to c we need relativistic quantum mechanics to explain  stuff.

For particle physics we need relativistic quantum mechanics to explain stuff.

Answer (score 1):

Pauli matrices play a part in both classical mechanics of spin and quantum mechanics of spin. Just because there is a Pauli matrix around, it does not necessarily mean there is quantum mechanics around.

The big difference between classical and quantum is that in quantum physical quantities are represented by operators as opposed to numbers or groups of numbers.

The classical mechanics of spin was already implicit in Poincare's work dating from early 20th century, but it is often forgotten now because people tend to learn about quantum physics before they learn about spin.

Answer (score 0):

What you said is true, but at the same time relativity didn't contain anything like probabilities or superpositions. For that reason and others, relativity did not already "know about" Quantum Field Theory.

I think a better interpretation is that incorporating the energy-momentum relation as a constraint to QM taught us more about what is necessary to make the two theories compatible. Through this constraint, it became clear that the compatibility of the two theories could only be achieved if, for example, antiparticles are incorporated. So a lot of QFT content followed from the constraint of SR + QM, but not from SR by itself.

Answer (score 0):

The Dirac equation is a classical relativistic wave equation, similar to Maxwell's equations. It doesn't have field quanta or entangled states or anything else that would justify calling it quantum.

Dirac was looking for a relativistic version of Schrödinger's equation and thought that the Dirac equation was a step in that direction, but he was wrong. We *still* don't have a relativistic version of the Schrödinger equation. It's known as the [problem of time](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Problem_of_time) (or at least it's closely related to it).

The anticommuting geometric algebra that Dirac discovered is a [Clifford algebra](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Clifford_algebra). Clifford algebras were known to mathematicians since the 1800s. The only reason you think of anticommuting algebras as related to quantum mechanics is that there's a tendency in physics to label anything that was discovered (by physicists) after quantum mechanics, and applied to quantum problems from the beginning, as quantum, even if it could just as well have been discovered earlier and applied to classical problems.